# what are the things you put in a showcase at home?

Tags: word-request

Is *decorations* the right word to describe things such as figurines, candelabra, handicrafts you put in a showcase to make it look attractive?

> Oh you got nice decorations in there.
>
> I need to get some decorations for my new furniture.

Do these sentences sound natural to a native speaker?

Comment: They are commonly called [*ornaments*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ornament). They might also be [*mementoes*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/memento), [*keepsakes*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/keepsake) or [*heirlooms*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/heirloom), depending on their origin and significance to the owner.

Comment: To which you might add knick-knacks and trinkets.

Comment: *Objets d'art*, too.

Comment: Statuettes, handicrafts, figurines,  artwork, trophies, keepsakes (+1 Mick), pieces, things, tchotchkes (originally from Yiddish/Polish).  "Things" or "pieces" could be used to encompass the full variety.

Comment: "Decorations for my furniture" would not be idiomatic. We could say "I need to get some new decorations".  It's "for my furniture" which makes it unnatural.

Comment: Then there is no one single word to describe these objects casually? Things used for decorative or cosmetic purposes here

Comment: I've got to get some new *curios*.  But it's a word that has fallen out of fashion. Not many people keep curio cabinets any more.  Curios are rare things or oddities.  *pieces for the cabinet* would be your best bet.

Comment: I can't think of a word specifically for things placed in a display cabinet. *Ornaments* is about as generic as you can get, but ornaments can be placed anywhere, and not all objects in a display cabinet need be purely ornamental.

Comment: Thank you all for suggesting all these. very helpful and informative, i could use all @TRomano Thank you :)

Comment: *Knick-knacks* per Ronald's comment is perfect if a) your objects don't have much intrinsic monetary value or b) they are indeed very valuable and the speaker likes to indulge in ironic understatement.

Comment: There is also *bric-a-brac*.

Comment: I'd call them garniture

Comment: wow thanks, I got my answer. I learnt many words today. I liked especifically _knick-knacks_ and _household ornaments_. I think I can go with them.

Comment: I think you meant "candelabras".

Comment: @user3169 yes, thank you for pointing that out. Im gona make it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are commonly called **[ornaments](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ornament)**:

> a small decorative object

Although the word [decoration](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/decoration?s=t) might sound appropriate from its definition:

> an addition that renders something more attractive or ornate; adornment

it doesn't really work here. If you told me someone had "nice decorations" in their home, I would assume you were talking about Christmas decorations, not items in a showcase.